# How to handle ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE?

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS app uses `$http.get()` with *https* urls. If the server is using a self-signed certificate Chrome will reject the request and log an error *ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE* to the console.

I would like to capture this specific error and prompt the user to configure their server with a valid certificate.

I've tried `$http.error` and `$httpProvider.interceptors` to get information about this error, but no relevant information is available in the error parameters.

I understand that Chrome is rejecting the request rather than the server, but using Angular, is there anyway to capture that Chrome has rejected the request with error *ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE*?

Comment: promise.error doesnt give you anything? That should give you the status and headers that come with the rejection.

Comment: status is 0, data is null and statusText is blank.

Comment: will that not work for what you need? Status 0 means the request isnt going through.

Comment: I am not familiar with status 0, so I guess it depends if there are many other cases where status 0 may be returned. Ideally I would still like to somehow get 'ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE', but if you think that 0 is a reliable status code for my situation, then please post it as an answer (preferably with a reference)

Comment: Seems like you also get '0' if you specify a domain that doesn't exist. Chrome will log 'ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my ionic Project, but there is No way to overcome this issue clientside, this is security issue, go to server settings for SSL configuration, change **DHPARAMS** to **2048 bit key**, that solved my issue,

Note  : my server is amazon s3

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while, trying to figure how to get a type of error in the $http error callback and show a helpful message to users. However, there seem to be no way to determine this specific error, the only way to determine it is to check whether the `response.status` is equal to `-1` (this happens if the request was interrupted for some reason) - but it also might be -1 in other cases, like missing internet connection. So eventually I edited the error message, shown on status -1, to explain user what might be wrong.

Also, in my case users have to enter the server address, so in addition I added checking whether it's not an IP address (IP addresses cannot have valid SSL certificate, only self-signed, which would cause aforementioned error):

```
if (server_url.match(/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)) {
    // Show error message like "only domain names are allowed"
}
```

Hope that helps.